# WordPress/WooCommerce URL for catgories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have always been able to determine two categories in the URL to filter the results to show items that meet both of the categories in the URL

For example: http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product-category/sale+shoes/

This would show only products that are in the 'sale' category and the 'shoes' category.

This is no longer working in the latest WordPress update. Does anyone have experince wiht this kind of thing.

I have contact WooCommerce support but they are extremely slow so hoping the community can help a brother out.

Comment: You should be checking if the item is on sale via it's properties not assigning a category to it because that is not a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

On new wordpress version,  old php and wordpress/woocommerce functions doesn't work.
So these problems often occurs after upgraded wordpress version.
In my thought,  some woocommerce functions related to product category will be changed.

If you let me know details info, I can fix them correctly
Or you can search positive solutions yourself on google depends on this answer

Comment: Also I just checked your site again. 
There is a jquery error.  I think it might be the cause.
It seems like it is good for you to fix it first

Comment: Thanks for this. I have updated this but now see an error saying 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'. Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You've got an issue with your custom.js file, change your code to this.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(function() {
        $('.home-box:empty').hide();
    });
});
```

Also for multiple categories you can pass this URL, separate categories with a comma.

```
http://www.shoezies.co.nz/?product_cat=sale,shoes
```

I can't check if it's working because your site is not rendering because of the jQuery error.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have updated this but now see an error saying 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Sorry I had an extra ' in it, updated the code will work now.